# Embed an $n\times n$ matrix into $R^{n^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

How to embed a matrix, for example, a $3x3$ singular matrix in to $R^9$?

How to compute the induced metric? Is it just the Frobenius norm of the matrix?

Many Thanks.
sam

Comment: The question is unclear.  For instance -- and this is just for starters; there are more serious objections -- "a matrix" is just a single object, so to embed "a matrix" into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is equivalent to just picking a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.  Doubtless this is not what you really mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What restrictions are there on the embedding?  If you just mean a bijection between $3 \times 3$ matrices and points in $\mathbb{R^9}$, there are many.  As there are $9$ entries in a $3 \times 3$ matrix, there are easy bijections taking each entry in the matrix to one component.  The bijection allows an easy metric, too-just use the usual metric in $\mathbb{R^9}$  It is true that the singular matrices have a constraint that reduces them to an eight-dimensional space.  This is the source of the first question-this embedding ignores the impact of singularity.

Comment: Ross actually the matrix is of dimension 5. So as you said think it will not provide a bijection.

Comment: @sam:  I picked up the 3 from your post, but if you want to embed $5 \times 5$ matrices in $\mathbb{R^{25}}$ it works exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the number of independent variables of the matrix is 5. matrix is still 3x3.

Comment: @sam:  what structure do you want to maintain with the embedding?  The embedding I gave does provide an injection into R^9.  For example, you might have some topology on your matrices that you want to correspond to the usual topology on R^9.  In that case, you will have to embed into a 5 dimensional subspace.

Comment: i will get back on this.